# Difference between 지 않다 and 지가 않다

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am always confused with these two. As 가, being used as subject particle, is of no meaning at all, I wonder what are the differences in meaning or usage.

I usually see 지 않다:

그녀는 예쁘지 않다.
넌 가지 않을 수 없다.

But I also, sometimes, see 지가 않다:
대답은 왜 들리지가 않나요?

[What noun particles can be attached to negatory -지?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/q/501/237) I had such a thought because of this question.

Any clarifications are much appreciated.

Comment: Nice question. +1) Please consider linking the previous question (I commented) or including some examples you find confusing. It will help you get a better answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using '가' after '지' is almost tautological and it adds a little emphasis. For example,

> 그녀는 예쁘지 않다. She is not pretty.
>
> 그녀는 예쁘지가 않다. She is not very pretty. (I wouldn't say it is the right
>   translation, but it is not easy to explain the difference in nuance.)

If you use '도' there, it would sound more insulting.

> 그녀는 예쁘지도 않다. She is not pretty, as well.

It adds another bad aspect of her in addition to the sentence previously mentioned or implied. For example,

> 그녀는 가난한데 예쁘지도 않다. She is poor and she is not pretty, as well.

If you use '는' in the sentence, it indicates a particularly bad aspect among good aspects. For example,

> 그녀는 부자다. 그녀는 차도 있다. (그런데) 그녀는 예쁘지는 않다. She is rich and has a car. But
>   she is not pretty.